# Why "Too many open files" error is occurred while opening a webpage with polipo installed on OS X 10.11.4?

Tags: macos, homebrew, proxy

I have installed `polipo-1.1.1` caching proxy on my OS X 10.11.4 with `homebrew`:

```
brew install polipo --with-large-chunks
```

Sometimes opening URLs ([this](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114514/can-the-default-permissions-on-dev-disk-be-changed) page for example) is failed with this error message:

```
504 Connect to apple.stackexchange.com:80 failed: Too many open files

The following error occurred while trying to access https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114514/can-the-default-permissions-on-dev-disk-be-changed:

504 Connect to apple.stackexchange.com:80 failed: Too many open files

Generated Sun, 22 May 2016 12:36:56 IRDT by Polipo on Hamids-MacBook-Pro.local:8123.
```

I have set up `~/.polipo` file as configuration file with `socksParentProxy` and `socksProxyType` parameters only.

The value of `ulimit -n` is `4864`.

In `/usr/local/var/cache/polipo` I have 510 folders and total size of this folders is `297 MB`.

Total number of files that are open with polipo with this command is `219`:

```
lsof -p $(pgrep polipo) | wc -l
```

Why this error is occurred and how can I prevent that?

Is there any configurations that I missed to set up?

Answer (score 1):

*This is a quick fix answer. If you know which configurations caused this problem please post your answer*

I didn't find out why this error occurs, but I solve the problem every time this error appears by running this command:

```
$ brew services restart polipo
Stopping `polipo`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `polipo` (label: homebrew.mxcl.polipo)
==> Successfully started `polipo` (label: homebrew.mxcl.polipo)
```

After restarting `polipo` instance, that error disappears.

**NOTE:** This command should be executed **OUT** of a `tmux` session. In a tmux session it will not work:

```
$ brew services restart polipo
~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.polipo.plist: Operation not permitted
==> Successfully started `polipo` (label: homebrew.mxcl.polipo)
```

If you are running such a session, detach the session with <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> (or any prefix key combination you set) and then press <kbd>d</kbd>. Now run that command.

**THE BEST ALTERNATIVE:** I used `reattach-to-user-namespace` to restart polipo service directly from tmux session:

```
$ brew install reattach-to-user-namespace
```

then `brew services` will work.

**UPDATE:** I found that my local polipo cache size is enough large:

```
$ du -d0 -h /usr/local/var/cache/polipo
13.8G    /usr/local/var/cache/polipo
```

There is a "purge" function that is explained [here](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jch/software/polipo/manual/Purging.html):

> The behavior of the -x flag is controlled by three configuration variables. The variable diskCacheUnlinkTime specifies the time during which an on-disk entry should remain unused before it is eligible for removal; it defaults to 32 days.

So I stopped polipo daemon with brew services:

```
$ brew services stop polipo
$ polipo -x
$ brew services start polipo
```

Now the size of local cache is reduced:

```
$ du -d0 -h /usr/local/var/cache/polipo
2.1G    /usr/local/var/cache/polipo
```

And it seems that the error is gone.